# problems after hosting a zend framwork project

Tags: php, zend-framework, web-hosting

After hosting my website, I had some configuration issues.

> Warning: require_once (Zend/application.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in //www/*******.com/public/index.php on line 22

I placed the Zend Framewotk library in `www/library`

```
www/application/
www/library/     <--- Zend Framework
www/public/
```

but after the addition of library another problem occurs:

> HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition has occurred while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Script of `public/index.php`

```php
<?php
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

defined('TMP_PATH')
    || define('TMP_PATH', realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../tmp/'));
// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
   APPLICATION_PATH . '/models',
   APPLICATION_PATH . '/models/generated',
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';  

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV, 
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);

$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

`$application->bootstrap()->run();` does nothing Comeback

Comment: What do your server logs say about the error?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a .htaccess configured corretly for that new hosting?
Error 500 is normally a server error, try to take a look in the
.htaccess.

Cheers,

Hugo

Comment: script of file .htaccess
public/.htaccess
[/code]SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L][/code]

thank you

Comment: script of file .htaccess
public/.htaccess

SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

thank you

Comment: sorry i can't add a block of script

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: require_once (Zend/application.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in //www/***.com/public/index.php on line 22

At first glance, it seems like a case-sensitivity issue: note the lowercase `a` in `Zend/application.php`.

However, your `public/index.php` seems to contain the correct:

`require_once 'Zend/Application.php'`

and the correct instantiation

```
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV, 
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
```

so there would be no need for the autoloader to try and load a class with the lower-case `a`.

Have you faithfully copied/pasted all the errors and code? Or might there be a transcription error in there somewhere?